# Cómo hago para tapar una imagen desde javascript y que al darle click se muestre?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estoy haciendo el juego del memorama para clase y cada imagen la he metido en la celda de una tabla, el problema es que no sé cómo hacer que no se vean y que se vean al hacer clic. He probado poniéndoles el atributo de visibility pero después no se puede poner visible otra vez porque al ser invisible no le puedes dar click.
No creo que haga falta que ponga código en este caso pero aquí os dejo la función en la que meto las imágenes en las celdas:

```
let ponerImagenes = () =>{
    cambiarArray();
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            document.getElementById("celda"+i+"."+j).appendChild(crearElemento('img', 'imagen'+i+"."+j));
            atributosImagen(document.getElementById('imagen'+i+"."+j));
        }
    }
}
let atributosImagen = (imagen) =>{
    imagen.setAttribute('src', cogerImagen());
    imagen.setAttribute('height', '60px');
    imagen.setAttribute('width', '90px');
    imagen.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te ayude pero no creo que sea necesario que ocultes la imagen, más bien tendrías que "sobreponer" algo encima de la imagen. Podrías crear un div con algún background o poner otra imagen.

Entonces quedaría así

```
document.getElementById("divEncimaDeLaImagen").addEventListener("click", function(){ imagen.style.visibility = 'visible'; imagen.style.zIndex = "1"; = 'visible'})
```

Aquí te dejo un link para que tengas una idea de cómo podría ser --> https://parzibyte.me/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Juego-de-memorama-en-JavaScript.png